# Selenium RunScript error "JavaScript is Null"

Tags: javascript, selenium

Using Selenium (2.5.0), one of the steps is to run a simple block of JavaScript:

**Command**: runScript

**Target**: javascript{document.getElementById("ui-datepicker-div").style.display='block';}

**Value**: [blank]

When running executing this command I get the error message

```
[error] Unexpected Exception: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null.
```

- The element ID definitely exists and I have tried this with text boxes etc too
- I can't see why this should return a null error as it doesn't really mean much

Can anyone suggest how I can fix this?

Comment: As far as i know target is the page you want to execute the command and value is the javascript code you want to run.

Comment: No unfortunately it occurs in either of the fields

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739605/getelementbyid-returns-null

Comment: Do the same thing outside Selenium and direct in Chrome or Firefox' console - at least then you know it's either Selenium at fault or something else.

Comment: @Arran It's just in Selenium.