# bootstrap tooltip success on first time but get Uncaught TypeError on second time

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip

I am trying to use bootstrap tooltip in my laravel project.

Here's my blade.php code:

```
...
@foreach($patients => $patient)  
  ...
  //This is the tooltip button
  <div data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-default comment-tooltip"  data-patient-id="{{ $patient->patient_id }}"><i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>


  //this is the div i wanna show after hovering tooltip button
  <div id="{{$patient->patient_id}}" style="visibility: hidden">
    some text
  </div>
  ...
@endforeach
...
```

And here's my javascript code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.comment-tooltip').tooltip({
      title: function () {
        var patient_id = $(this).data('patient-id');
        var element = document.getElementById(patient_id);
        element.style.visibility = 'visible';
        return element;
      },
      html: true,
      placement: 'right',
      callback: function(){
        var patient_id = $(this).data('patient-id');
        var element = document.getElementById(patient_id);
        element.style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
 });
```

And when I hover the button on first time, it works

But when I hover it on second time, it shows error message below in console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

Hope someone can help me fix this problem. Thanks!!

Comment: This is because `var element = document.getElementById(patient_id);` is `null` the second time. Without seeing more code and having a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to help.

Comment: [getElementById returns null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739605/getelementbyid-returns-null)

Answer (score -1):

You can use below for tooltip

`<div data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Message will be here to show on mouse over." data-placement="right" data-container="body">
    <i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>`

no need for this long code

Answer (score -1):

```
<span class="fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" title="your message here"> 
<script>
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
</script>
```

you do not want to worry about callback function.
this is very simple way i am using it in many projects.
very simple and effective.
as i understand you are getting a problem to show tooltip.
correct me if i am wrong.